# SharePoint and traditional dotx / xltx templates

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document

We have a lot of business templates (circa 50+) and have recently moved to SharePoint.

Our templates are stored in a document library and we have become aware that if someone opens a template now from the SharePoint library, any changes are saved back to the template.

Obviously the expected action would be as before, the user should be prompted to save the dotx as a docx. This is not the case.

If we use the "Upload template" option on SharePoint, we will have a dropdown with 50+ choices which is not practical.

Also we would have to implement the templates across every document library - not practical.

Is there any other ways to achieve what is the expected action on opening a templates (dotx / xltx) on SharePoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a document library for the purpose of storing these templates.

Permissions would be set up in a way that your users have only read access to these template files.

Using this, people can´t update the template as they are not allowed to save to the library.

Answer (score 0):

Do not let ordinary users directly open the template, as Phil suggested, you could set unique permissions for the library where templates are stored.

You can categorize these templates and use them in different libraries to avoid a drop-down menu with more than 50 options.